# Monitoring App Activity using either the Android or iOS SDK

Tags: android, ios, monitoring, tracking, usage-statistics

Is there a way I can monitor App Activity beyond whether or not an App has launched, using the above mentioned. If not is there a way I can monitor the usage of an ePub from iBooks or any epid reader?

Answer (score 0):

I wont be able to help you with your IOS question. But for android there are tools to monitor your App's activity. I cant speak for every developer program but when using Eclipse with the android SDK you will be profited with a rather large ammount of tools.

In Eclipse you can find these tools trough: Window>Show view>other (or hit ALT+SHIFT+Q , Q). In the screen you can look for the tools listed in the Android folder.

Comment: Oh, what I meant was monitor the activity of an App or Usage, of an App that is already running on the device.

Comment: Ah oke my bad. Well I'm not 100% sure about it but I don't think android logs that. You could put in some code that does the logging for you (Save the number of start-ups somewhere in your options or local database).

Comment: Cool thanks, it turns out there is no practical way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can use Instruments to monitor app activity via USB.

Select Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments. Select a template based on the data you want and select a target app. Hit record and you're all set!

Comment: Oh, what I meant was monitor the activity of an App or Usage, of an App that is already running on the device.

Comment: Over a long period of time?